# Vue Prop undefined in child component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass an array that inside an object from a parent component to a child component but answers is coming up undefined. When checking the prop in the parent component the data is there, but when it gets past to the child it is undefined.

```
Vue.component('single-question', {
    props: ['question'],
    data: function () {
        let vm = this
        return {
            answers: vm.question.answers
        }
    },
    template: `<div class="question mb-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="class-title">{{question.questionId}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{question.questionText}}</p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" v-bind:href="'#answerArea' + question.questionId" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="answerArea">List answers</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <answer-area v-bind:id="'answerArea' + question.questionId" v-bind:answers="question.answers"></answer-area>
            </div>`   
})

Vue.component('answer-area', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            show: false
        }
    },
    props: ['answers'],
    template: `<div class="collapse" id="">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <ol>
                        <li v-for="answer in answers" v-bind:key="answer.answerId"></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>`

})
```

edit: Here is where the parent is declared

```
<div id="question-area">
            <single-question v-for="question in questions" v-bind:key="question.questionId" v-bind:question="question"
                v-bind:id="question.questionId"></single-question>
        </div>
```

Parent data:

```
    new Vue ({
        el: '#question-area',
        data: {
            questions: [{
               "answers": [{
                    "answerId": 21,
                    "questionId": 1,
                    "answerText": "One",
                    "iscorrect": false
                },
                {
                    "answerId": 40,
                    "questionId": 1,
                    "answerText": "In",
                    "iscorrect": false
         }],
            "questionId": 1,
            "classCode": "123",
            "questionText": "Result",
        }],

        },
    })
```

Query:

```
$.getJSON(prestring + "/api/v1/classes/"+parsed.classcode+"/questions", function(json) {
            vm.questions = json
            vm.questions.forEach(question => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: prestring + "/api/v1/questions/" + question.questionId + "/answers",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    //async: false,
                    success: function (json) {
                        question["answers"] = json
                        // question["answers"].push(json)
                    }
                })
            })
        })
```

Comment: _"answers is coming up undefined"_ where? What **exactly** is the error message?

Comment: Can you paste the parent's declaration?

Comment: @Phil Using the Vue chrome extension it is showing the the prop 'answers' is undefined, even though in the prop 'question' in the parent component contains the array called answers.

Comment: @acdcjunior, Is that what you meant by parent's declaration

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem ~ https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/14841/

Comment: @Liam87 Yes, but we need a bit more, actually. Like the JS code (especially `data`).

Comment: @acdcjunior, I added the vue instance and the data field

Comment: @acdcjunior, I actually found the problem, the data for answers had not loaded from the ajax query since it first grabs the questions then grabs the answers after with a separate query, I will have to rework how I am grabbing the data.

Comment: Can you show the Ajax query? You probably are falling into one of the reactivity caveats.

Comment: @acdcjunior, I added the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would have to check what's in your `data` to be sure, but you are probably facing one of the [**Change Detection Caveats**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Try using `Vue.set()` to create your `answers` property, as below:

```
$.getJSON(prestring + "/api/v1/classes/"+parsed.classcode+"/questions", 
function(json) {
        vm.questions = json
        vm.questions.forEach(question => {
            $.ajax({
                url: prestring + "/api/v1/questions/" + question.questionId + "/answers",
                dataType: 'json',
                //async: false,
                success: function (json) {
                    // question["answers"] = json
                    Vue.set(question, 'answers', json); // changed this line
                    // question["answers"].push(json)
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I recommend that linked doc. This actually is a very common issue. Getting acquainted with it will help you bit time in the future!